# How do you get IOptions<T> values from services?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm trying to do TDD while developing but I am struggling. My first test I can successfully get the options set in services.AddAuthentication(...), but I am not able to get the options from .AddCookie(..) that is added onto the previous call. During debug I do see that there is an IPostConfigureOptions added for CookieAuthenticationOptions, and I suspect that it somehow alters the default option values, but I don't know how to get it.

Code to be tested:

```
public static void AddOpenIdConnect(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => { options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None; });

    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        options =>
        {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Error/403");
        }
    );
}
```

My first test ensured the AuthenticationOptions were set, and it passes:

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddOpenIdConnect_Should_AddAuthenticationOptions()
{
    //  arrange
    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    //  act
    services.AddOpenIdConnect();

    //  assert
    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var authOptions = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AuthenticationOptions>>();

    authOptions.Value.DefaultScheme.Should().Be(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    authOptions.Value.DefaultChallengeScheme.Should().Be(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

This method fails, as AccessDeniedPath returns the default setting and not the setting that the code being tested sets (you can see that I commented out the check on ExpireTimeSpan as it fails as well.)

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddOpenIdConnect_Should_AddCookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    //  arrange
    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    //  act
    services.AddOpenIdConnect();

    //  assert
    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var authCookieOptions = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>>();

    //authCookieOptions.Value.ExpireTimeSpan.Should().Be(TimeSpan.FromHours(2));
    authCookieOptions.Value.SlidingExpiration.Should().BeTrue();
    authCookieOptions.Value.AccessDeniedPath.Should().Be("/Error/403");
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, as I still have to tack on a ".AddOpenIdConnect(options =>" after this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/42b3fada3144fed68e5b20821d99c3684f1c3543/src/Security/Authentication/Cookies/src/CookieExtensions.cs#L26) for the `AddCookie` extension shows that is uses the authentication scheme to configure a named option when adding `CookieAuthenticationOptions`

```
public static AuthenticationBuilder AddCookie(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, 
string authenticationScheme, string displayName, Action<CookieAuthenticationOptions> configureOptions)
{
    builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IPostConfigureOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, PostConfigureCookieAuthenticationOptions>());
    builder.Services.AddOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(authenticationScheme).Validate(o => o.Cookie.Expiration == null, "Cookie.Expiration is ignored, use ExpireTimeSpan instead.");
    return builder.AddScheme<CookieAuthenticationOptions, CookieAuthenticationHandler>(authenticationScheme, displayName, configureOptions);
}
```

[Source Code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/42b3fada3144fed68e5b20821d99c3684f1c3543/src/Security/Authentication/Cookies/src/CookieExtensions.cs#L26)

Note the

```
builder.Services.AddOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(authenticationScheme) //<-- Named option
```

Thus the same scheme used when the option was registered will need to be used in order to access the name option

This can be done using [`IOptionsSnapshot<TOptions>.Get(String)` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptionssnapshot-1.get)

```
//...omitted for brevity

// Assert
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
IOptionsSnapshot<CookieAuthenticationOptions> namedOptionsAccessor = 
    provider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsSnapshot<CookieAuthenticationOptions>>();

CookieAuthenticationOptions options = 
    namedOptionsAccessor.Get(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

options.ExpireTimeSpan.Should().Be(TimeSpan.FromHours(2));
options.SlidingExpiration.Should().BeTrue();
options.AccessDeniedPath.Should().Be("/Error/403");
```

Comment: Thank you @Nkosi. I didn't realize I would have to use IOptionsSnapshot<> to get the values as I haven't done a lot with the Options pattern yet.